# container management in Java

Tags: java, containers

I'm currently trying to make a way teachers can make classroom-private (modded) Minecraft servers. It is for a project I'm working on which will make Minecraft useable for teaching physics and chemistry.

There would be one central server computer which would run several servers, one for every lesson. Children should only be able to connect to the lesson they're in, I've already thought of a solution for this, but it would have to use something like containers.

The solution I was thinking about would use docker, but I'd like to have something completely Java-based, which I could package with the jar, so there are no pre-requisites (I'm already including the JRE).

So, my question is;
**What container management library can I use that I can package in a jar and run on windows?**

Comment: what do you mean? do you want  to package your application docker image in a jar?

Comment: I'd like to have a docker alternative which can be packaged in my jar, so I can manage it with java code. I know about the java docker API but it doesn't seem to fit my needs as the person running the jar needs to have docker up and running already; I'd prefer to start it in my main class

Comment: If you want to provide a binary which someone can run on JVM, packing your app as a fat jar would be sufficient. That's the simplest solution.

Comment: A fat jar was something I was thinking about, but I need something that I could pack with the jar, that's what I was asking for

Comment: @EwanArends see my answer then. Jlink (or javapackager) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect usecase for the new `jlink` tool introduced with Java 9.

With `jlink`, you can build your custom JRE image, stripped down to contain only what's really needed to run your application. Also, `jlink` is able to produce a *native* (`batch` file in case of Windows) executable for running your Bundle without using the command line.

See more of [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm#JSWOR-GUID-CECAC52B-CFEE-46CB-8166-F17A8E9280E9) at the Oracle site.

Comment: I didn't know Jlink could be used for images? is this possible at runtime? thanks in advance!

Comment: @EwanArends you'll have to use jlink to **build** your final runnable bundle. Once built, it will run everywhere with its bundled/custom JRE.

Comment: So how would i go about packing docker with this?

Comment: @EwanArends you don't need Docker. The JRE is bundled inside the produced bundle. You don't need an external JVM. Your application is completely self-contained.

Comment: @EwanArends see for example https://steveperkins.com/using-java-9-modularization-to-ship-zero-dependency-native-apps/

Comment: The thing is, I want to be able to manage several running servers, adding players to the whitelists, and such. The amount of servers should be dynamic

Comment: @EwanArends Then you need something like Kubernetes or Docker Swarm. But they're totally separated. Or just multiple Docker containers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190389/discussion-between-ewan-arends-and-lppedd).